# $ \int_1^{\infty} \int_1^{\infty} f(x,y) \space dx \space dy $ special case?

Tags: calculus, integration, closed-form

Consider

$$ A = \int_1^{\infty} \int_1^{\infty} f(x,y) \space dx \space dy $$

$$ B =  \int_1^{\infty} f(x,y) \space dx $$

$$ C = \int_1^{\infty} f(x,y) \space dy $$

$$ D = \int_1^{\infty} \int_1^{\infty} f(x,y) - f(y,x) \space dx \space dy $$

Where $A,B,C$ converge to a positive real value.
$D$ also converges to a real value , but not necc positive. $A$ has a closed form but $B$ , $C$ and $D$ do not.

What are typical solutions for $f(x,y) $ ?
And how to find them ?

Comment: The inspiration was fubini’s theorem : in this case changing the order of integration does not help ...

Comment: $f(x,y) = g(x)-g(y)$ for some nasty enough $g$

Comment: $f(x,y)=e^{-(x^2+y^2)}$ is a good example.  The double integral can be evaluated explicitly by switching to polar coordinates.  The individuals are will need erf for representation.

Comment: Thank you mercio and herb steinberg. I forgot to mention symmetry. I made an important edit !